# Neo4j neverending slow node creating

Tags: performance, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

have dataset in .csv file with format

```
"title"|year|"word"
"Into the Wild"|2007|"abandoned-bus"
"Into the Wild"|2007|"adolescence"
"Into the Wild"|2007|"adoption"
```

This file has over 4M lines.

I have database running on remote super-computer which I connect using ssh tunnel. I create 2 indices:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :MOVIE(title)
CREATE INDEX ON :KEYWORD(word)
```

Then I execute query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/Users/.../Data/rels.csv" AS csv
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (m:MOVIE {title:csv.title })
ON CREATE SET m.year = toInt(csv.year)
MERGE (k:KEYWORD {word:csv.word})
```

After some time, I don't know one hour, information about query executing disappears or an Unknown error appears. But when I go to localhost:7474/webadmin in stats there is count of nodes increasing very slowly - 5-8 nodes in about 10 seconds.

When I execute query: (I can because there is no running query shown)

```
match (m)
return count(m)
```

there are about 79K nodes. But count is increasing over 21 hours. And I need create about 1.2M nodes and than make about 4M relationships between them. When I make basic computation, creating that 1.2M nodes will last about 13 days. And really don't want to know how long will last creating 4M relationships.

**What is happening? How to fasten it? What can I do?**
Please help.

**NOTE:**

I already created nodes of MOVIEs and KEYWORDs in past and did it from separate csv files containing only MOVIEs or KEYWORDs and did it without USING PERIODIC COMMIT but manually selected about 60K of lines and executed query on it. But I removed them all to make it in 2 queries also with relationships and with no work with dividing csv files. Can't imagine to manually divide 4M lines file into 60K lines files.

Comment: You can maybe adjust the periodic commit to 1000 and also share your neo4j-wrapper configuration, especially the settings for the java heap size

Comment: What is worse, I don't have access to them cause this files of database are on that remote computer. But I remember that my tutor set them to large values cause of that computer should do it easily. But where can I adjust periodic commit? And I also think that this wrapper file is not in all versions, I mean in windows version there is no such file but in linux version it should be there.

Comment: USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV ...

Comment: How can periodic commit limit affect how long it runs? I tried it now on my local database on my laptop I have no 40K nodes in maybe 2 hours but now it is slowing down and I'm only on 40K and need 1.2M and can't imagine how long it will last to make 4M relationships between nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a procedure little bit.

1. Load all 160K Keywords from keyword csv containing only keywords (few milliseconds)

   `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:c:/.../kw.csv' as csv
   CREATE (:KEYWORD {word:csv.word})`
2. Load all 2M Movies from movie csv containing only movie titles and years (few seconds)

   `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:c:/.../mov.csv' as csv
   CREATE (:MOVIE {title:csv.title, year: toInt(csv.year)})`
3. Create indexes on MOVIE and KEYWORD

   `CREATE INDEX ON :MOVIE(title)
   CREATE INDEX ON :MOVIE(year)
   CREATE INDEX ON :KEYWORD(word)`
4. Load relationships from csv containing movies titles, years and keywords (this takes few hours but was quite fast, could see progress in webadmin interface)

   `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:c:/.../rels.csv' as csv
   MATCH (m:MOVIE {title:csv.title, year: toInt(csv.year)})
   MATCH (k:KEYWORD {word:csv.word})
   MERGE (m)-[:HAS {weight:1}]->(k)`

Hope this help somebody in future.

Comment: You probably ran into this issue: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Comment: change your last query to: `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:c:/.../rels.csv' as csv
MATCH (m:MOVIE {title:csv.title}) WHERE m.year=toInt(csv.year)
MATCH (k:KEYWORD {word:csv.word})
CREATE (m)-[:HAS {weight:1}]->(k)`

Comment: I'm done now, my last query runs fine, it takes few hours but it runs fine. If I can ask, what is the difference? between mine and yours? That your query firstly find movie with specific title using index and than tries to check if it has specific year? I admit, it can be faster. But thanks for now mine works relatively fine too :)

Comment: @MichaelHunger your updated query is not good. Last `CREATE statement` makes multiple relationships between `(m)` and `(k)` when there are same lines in csv. And there are, that dataset is crap but, what can I do, it is huge dataset from imdb repository.